# The edit distance from a large complete $p$-partite graph to the Turan graph

Tags: graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

Let $K=K(V_1,V_2,\cdots,V_p)$ be a $p$-partite complete graph on $n$ vertices and $T_p(n)$ be the Turan graph.

Show that: if $e(K)\geq e(T_r(n))-t$ then $$\sum_{k=1}^p\left(|V_k|-\frac{n}{p}\right)^2\leq 4t.$$

Furthermore, $$|E(K)\Delta E(T_p(n))|\leq 2n\sqrt{\frac{t}{p}}.$$

This statement was claimed in [Furedi](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0095895615000568) which can be proved by 'simple calculation'.

I have no idea towards the first inequality. For the second one, I managed to prove a weak one from the first:

$$ 4tp\geq\sum\left(|V_k|-\frac{n}{p}\right)^2\sum 1^2\geq \left(\sum \left||V_k|-\frac{n}{p}\right|\right)^2.$$

Since we need to edit at most $n$ edges for a vertex, then $|E(K)
\Delta E(T_p(n))|\leq 2n\sqrt{tp}.$

Any idea is welcomed! :)

Remark: differed by a constant is not important. So we no longer need to juggle with the ceil or floor function in most cases.

Comment: Actually, is $e(K)\geq e(T_r(n))-t$ is even possible? Doesn't $T_r(n)$ maximize the number of edges of a graph without a $K_{r+1}$? If $K$ is a $r$-partite complete graph, it too doesn't contain $K_{r+1}$, so it must have less edges than the Turan graph...correct me if I'm missing something.